# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character?

Tags: c#, base64

Here I am trying to decrpyt a string using private key and getting an error like:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

The string(i.e string authenticationString) which i am trying to decrpyt is:

> Z7W7ja7G+NB3+QsbNnsz7zCkt1xeZ1PQC606wZzQG2McjExT6WjFPDWNpVSqcw1X+K6TERZUK4677m5Z6x9TuxLxyA8h8LmB4dwcJsQZGoVg0mOLsxO6GZmdThLyQOxQgnA7sk4KHLv6DrVswtVzjM/gJouvDKHTC7+NZmjhWwA=

and my code is:

```
 internal virtual Credentials Extract(string basicAuthenticationCredentials)
      {
         string authenticationString = RemoveBasicFromAuthenticationString(basicAuthenticationCredentials);
         string privateKeyPath = @"D:\Bala\MVC\RestService\RestClient\Scripts\PrivateKey.xml";
         myRsa.LoadPrivateFromXml(privateKeyPath);  // Loading the Private key
         RSACryptoServiceProvider localRsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
         localRsa.FromXmlString(File.ReadAllText(privateKeyPath));
         byte[] decMessage = Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationString);
         byte[] message = null;
         // Calling the right decryption method according to the user selection
         message = myRsa.PrivateDecryption(decMessage);
         string au = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
         return extractor.Extract(decoder.Decode(au));
      }
```

and in string `au` I am geting a value like:

> d��!���u�I|�3��iaȴ{ȱ��q��A��z��ta �i8?�-�[�#�*&��Y^l,�v������ā�\�f�$R�V����&g;�

and am getting this error for a particular username password only. Others are working fine.
Any suggestion?

EDIT:
  The error is throwing in this line  byte[] decodedStringInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedValue);

```
internal virtual string Decode(string encodedValue)
      {
         byte[] decodedStringInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedValue);
         return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decodedStringInBytes);
      }
```

EDIT 2:

```
internal class DecodedCredentialsExtractor
   {
      internal virtual Credentials Extract(string credentials)
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials))
         {
            string[] credentialTokens = credentials.Split(':');
            //string securityToken = string.Empty;
            if (credentialTokens.Length == 2)
            {
               return new Credentials(credentialTokens[0], credentialTokens[1]);
            }
         }

         throw new ArgumentException("The supplied credential string is invalid, it should comply to [username:password]", "credentials");
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't understand how you can be getting an exception in `FromBase64String` *and* still get a value for `au`...

Comment: And your base64 encoded string is fine...

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: @jon that au is not a proper value right?? for other strings and all getting a au value like 'c2FjaGluOnBhc3N3b3Jk'

Comment: Why are you using both `Encoding.UTF8` and `Encoding.ASCII` in your code?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are getting a value for `au` suggests that it isn't the base-64 decode in the question that is erroring. I'm going to make the assumption that is actually the last line that is failing, and is expecting base-64 - and you are using UTF-8 (backwards, I suspect, which isn't valid). Try:

```
     message = myRsa.PrivateDecryption(decMessage);
     string au = Convert.ToBase64String(message);
     return extractor.Extract(decoder.Decode(au));
```

Comment: @bala3569 right; so that supports the view that `Decode` expects base-64, not a decoded (via UTF-8) string

Comment: (reply to a now-deleted comment)  @bala3569 have you tried *the thing I already suggested*? Although frankly: the main thing to do is to make sure you understand and document what each method expects; i.e. if it is a string, is is actual text, base-64, etc; if it is a blob, what is it.

Comment: Look at my edit 2..there it is throwing the error The supplied credential string is invalid, it should comply to [username:password]

Answer (score -4):

Uninstall 64 bit c++ redistribution and install x84 instead and you should have no problem.
Good luck!